# Using the DoctrineObjectConstructor, how are new entities created?

Tags: jmsserializerbundle

I am attempting to use JMSSerializerBundle to consume JSON into Doctrine entities.  I need to both create new entities where they do not already exist in the database, and update existing entities when they do already exist.  I am using the [DoctrineObjectConstructor](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/Construction/DoctrineObjectConstructor.php) included in the JMSSerializer package to help with this.  When I consume JSON which contains a property designated as an identifier, such as:

> `{
>           "id": 1,
>           "some_other_attribute": "stuff"
>       }`

by attempting to deserialize it, JMSSerializer causes warnings and eventually dies with an exception for attempting to utilize reflection to set properties on a null value.  The warnings all look like this:

> `PHP Warning:  ReflectionProperty::setValue() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in /Users/cdonadeo/Repos/Ubertester/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericDeserializationVisitor.php on line 176`

If I manually insert an entity with ID 1 in my database and make another attempt then I receive no errors and everything appears to be working correctly, but I'm now short half my functionality.  I looked at the code for the DoctrineObjectConstructor class, and at the top is a comment:

> `/**
>    * Doctrine object constructor for new (or existing) objects during deserialization.
>    */`

But I don't see how it could possibly create a new a new entity because after the `construct()` function has done all of its checks, at the end it calls:

> `$object = $objectManager->find($metadata->name, $identifierList);`

And since the identifier does not exist in the database the result is null which is ultimately what gets returned from the function.  This explains why inserting a row in the database with the appropriate ID makes things work: `find()` now returns a proper Entity object, which is what the rest of the library expects.

Am I using the library wrong or is it broken?  I forked the Git repo and [made an edit](https://github.com/cdonadeo/serializer/commit/e10c174db982f744cda818736769e41963139e66), and trying it out everything seems to work more or less the way I expected.  That edit does have some drawbacks that make me wonder if I'm not just making this more difficult than it has to be.  The biggest issue I see is that it will cause persisted and unpersisted entities to be mixed together with no way to tell which ones are which, but I don't know if that's even a big deal.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: That's too bad that you did not get any response.. I am facing the same issue

Comment: @mr12086 @Delphine As of 1.7 it looks like you can pass `DoctrineObjectConstructor::ON_MISSING_FALLBACK` as the third option to the constructor for `DoctrineObjectConstructor` to make it create new entities that aren't in the database yet.  There's a [pull request](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/751) and mention in the [release notes](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/releases/tag/1.7.0).  I don't have any PHP projects at the moment, so I haven't tested this but it should work.  Released just over a week ago - timing really is everything!

Answer (score 0):

For Doctrine entities use configuration:

```
jms_serializer:
    object_constructors:
        doctrine:
            fallback_strategy: "fallback" # possible values ("null" | "exception" | "fallback")
```

see configuration reference https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle/master/configuration